# Google App Engine "Error parsing ./app.yaml: Unknown url handler type"

Tags: php, python, mysql, google-app-engine, phpmyadmin

I'm following a tutorial on how to install PHPMyAdmin on Google App Engine and I followed the directions exactly and when I go to push the app, I'm getting a parsing error. This is the tutorial link:
https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2013/05/26/setting-up-phpmyadmin-on-app-engine/

I searched out Stackoverfllow and found some questions with the same error, and almost everyone said their is an indention issue that causes it, but I have reviewed my file several times an have not found any indentations in the app.yaml file.

This is my app.yaml file

```
application: phpmyadmin2121
version: phpmyadmin
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
static_files: phpMyAdmin/\1
upload: phpMyAdmin/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
application_readable: true

- url: /(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
static_files: phpMyAdmin/\1
upload: phpMyAdmin/(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
application_readable: true

- url: /(.*\.(php$))
script: phpMyAdmin/\1
secure: always
login: admin

- url: /(.+)
script: phpMyAdmin/index.php
secure: always
login: admin

- url: /
script: phpMyAdmin/index.php
secure: always
login: admin
```

Here is the command line prompt showing the error:

Michaels-MacBook-Air:phpMyAdmin Mike$ appcfg.py -R -A phpmyadmin2121 -V phpmyadmin update .
    Usage: appcfg.py [options] update  | [file, ...]

```
appcfg.py: error: Error parsing ./app.yaml: Unknown url handler type.
<URLMap 
    secure=default 
    static_files=None 
    application_readable=None 
    auth_fail_action=redirect 
    require_matching_file=None 
    static_dir=None 
    redirect_http_response_code=None 
    http_headers=None 
    url=/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$)) 
    script=None 
    upload=None 
    api_endpoint=None 
    expiration=None 
    position=None 
    login=optional 
    mime_type=None
    >
  in "./app.yaml", line 8, column 1
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In case anyone else comes across this, I had the same issue. You must add **TWO** spaces for all subdirectories. Make sure the words are in line with "url".

Doesn't work:

```
- url: /
script: phpMyAdmin/index.php
secure: always
login: admin
```

Doesn't work:

```
- url: /
 script: phpMyAdmin/index.php
 secure: always
 login: admin
```

WORKS:

```
- url: /
  script: phpMyAdmin/index.php
  secure: always
  login: admin
```

Also, change the line to update the app from this:

`appcfg.py -R -A my_application_id -V phpmyadmin update .`

To this:

`appcfg.py --oauth2 -R -A my_application_id -V phpmyadmin update .`

For some odd reason, the first command asks for your email and password (my personal email didn't work). Using the second command with the --oauth2 option just works.

Comment: This is why I hate YAML. Requires very good eyesight to tell whether you've got the right number of spaces.

Comment: Yo da (wo)MAN!  spent way too much time trying to fix this!

Comment: Big-time answer right here.

Answer (score 14):

In my case, it was *not* a whitespace issue.

I originally had the app.yaml file:

```
runtime: nodejs12

handlers:
- url: /.*
  secure: always

... more handlers here ...
```

which produced the error when deploying

```
Unknown url handler type.
<URLMap 
    secure=always
    ...
    >
```

The docs at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_element indicated that I was missing `script: auto` in my handler element.

> In order to use static handlers, at least one of your handlers must contain the line script: auto or define an entrypoint element to deploy successfully.

So I updated my app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs12

handlers:
- url: /.*
  secure: always
  script: auto

... more handlers here ...
```

which deploys successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a space for any sub item. PHP uses the same parser as python. In python white space is used to denote blocks.

```
application: phpmyadmin2121
version: phpmyadmin
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  static_files: phpMyAdmin/\1
  upload: phpMyAdmin/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  application_readable: true

- url: /(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  static_files: phpMyAdmin/\1
  upload: phpMyAdmin/(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  application_readable: true

- url: /(.*\.(php$))
  script: phpMyAdmin/\1
  secure: always
  login: admin

- url: /(.+)
  script: phpMyAdmin/index.php
  secure: always
  login: admin

- url: /
  script: phpMyAdmin/index.php
  secure: always
  login: admin
```

Comment: I tried, but still returned an error, the only thing different is now it says column 2. its strange because my other app gets no error and it has something similar

Comment: Odd I just tried it on my end and it worked. First thing I noticed is your appID in the app.yaml doesn't match the one you put in the command line. can you run tree /f /a > tree.txt and include the 5 lines ?

Comment: I changed it on purpose, but I forgot to change the command line copy and paste, so thanks. I just figured its not wise to post the names of your apps here, but thanks for trying

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. The mistake in the tutorial are indeed the two missing spaces on the rows below the dash, so change from

```
handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
static_files: phpMyAdmin/\1
upload: phpMyAdmin/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
```

...

to

```
handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  static_files: phpMyAdmin/\1
  upload: phpMyAdmin/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
```

...